# While en angularjs

Tags: angularjs, while

necesito asesoría en el siguiente problema:

estoy trabajando en un software de toma de numero, tengo dos instancias de trabajo. Una es el Totem que es donde yo pido, tomo, adquiero mi numero para que me atiendan y el otro es el panel de control, un Web-app que es donde yo llamo el numero para atenderlo...

en este caso el problema lo tengo en el web-app:

Aquí necesito actualizar el numero actual de atención y la lista de números de espera cada vez que llamo a un numero para atenderlo...

el problema es que la respuesta esta asincrónica, puede tardar 5 seg como 3 seg... en traerme los cambios para mostrarlos en el front. Entonces al hacer click en llamar no me sirve poner las función de actualizar a los nuevos números porque este lo ara antes de la respuesta y no se vera efectuado el cambio...

¿Soluciones?

Primero pensé en utilizar un `$timeout` de 3 seg pero al ser asincrónico no me sirve y ponerle mas tiempo ya es latoso...

Ahora se me ocurrió hacer una especie de `while` es decir que  cuando apriete el botón llamar, este constantemente preguntando por la función que me trae el  numero actual  de atención (`$scope.cola()`)  si esta es distinta que actualize los datos (`$scope.actualizar()`) y corte el `while` de lo contrario que siga hasta encontrar diferencia...

Tengo `$scope.cola()` una función que trae:

> Letra
>   NumeroActual

y `$scope.actualizar()` que ejecuta:

> `$scope.cola()`   (trae el numero actual de atención)
>   `$scope.tickets()` (trae los números que están en espera)

```
$scope.cola() mas simplificado seria:


   $scope.Cola = function(){

 Ticket.Colaservices({

  id_usuario: LoginData.getData().id_usuario,
  token: LoginData.getData().token,
  id_sucursal: LoginData.getData().id_sucursal,
  id_moduloatencion: LoginData.getData().moduloatencion_id

}, function(response){

  $scope.DateCola = response.data;
   var numeroAct = response.data.numero
   window.localStorage.setItem('number', numeroAct);
});
```

}

Acá en la función de respuesta guardo la letra actual en la variable `numeroact` y la almaceno en un `localStorage`.

En mi function llamar seria:

```
  $scope.llamar = function(){

   var num = window.localStorage.getItem('number');

   Llamado.Llamar({
   id_usuario: LoginData.getData().id_usuario,
   token: LoginData.getData().token,
   id_sucursal: LoginData.getData().id_sucursal,
   id_moduloatencion: LoginData.getData().moduloatencion_id
 },function(response){

   necesito estar ejecutando en un bucle $scope.cola() hasta que num      cambie y y cuando lo haga ejecute $scope.actualizar()
```

})
  }

Please ayuda y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tu solucion es $interval

```
let resultado = $interval(function() {
            let esMantequilla = false;
            //lo que quieras
            if(esMantequilla){
              $interval.cancel("valor de retorno si lo deseas");
            }
          }, 100);
```

el numero 100 es el retardo(delay) que se va a ejecutar por funcion

Comment: como corto el $interval?

Comment: $interval.cancel(resultado);

Comment: agrego un ejemplo para otros fines https://jsfiddle.net/ssenkus/krsz9/

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que necesitas sería usar `promise`.

Echa un ojo que hay muchisima documentación sobre ello. https://carlosazaustre.es/blog/uso-de-promesas-en-angularjs/

Básicamente así puedes lanzar una petición y esperar a obtener una respuesta para lanzar la siguiente operación. De forma que llamarías a la función que te da nuevo ticket y cuando termine llamarías a las de actualizar.